# Vue app Enterprise Edition : how to manage a clean codebase for an Open Source Software project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, architecture, frontend

I am working on an open source software https://github.com/kestra-io/. We want to add a EE layer.

I am quite fluent in Vue js, but I really wonder how to manage some EE private code that will enhence the OSS core.

I don't really know what to search for some ressources about this topic. and the searches I did has no really relevant results.

This question is an achitectural topic where I would like some advices on how to setup the EE edition of this project:

We already thought about some possibles solution but I would like some external advices if possible before starting any impementation in some possibly dead end issues.

The patterns we  thought about are the following :

- Overload the webpack configuration to tell the build system integrate some EE components on the fly : this sounds quite tricky and unsure about the result.
- Integrate the OSS core code as a library requiring some quite important transformations on the actual codebase and some dynamic override tricks acheive what we want : I think it needs quite a lot of rework.
- Do some sort of custom script with a configuration file that would transform the repository with EE components that we would trigger at build time : quite dirty and sounds just a simpler but poorer solution than handling this with webpack.

And that's almost all for now. I d'ont have many other ideas at the moment about this and this is quite blocking.

Is there any well known / main stream way to do this properly ?

If not, I guess some of you have already meet this topic and found some sort of solution ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I did a related in Vue forums thread : https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-app-enterprise-edition-how-to-manage-a-clean-codebase-for-an-open-source-software-project/94099